# Public Official API for Google Play?

Tags: google-play

I was wondering if there was an official Google Play API available yet? Having looked at old postings there did not appear to be one circa 2010/11 but things may have changed?

There is still the unofficial:

https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ but that does not look to be maintained. I also came across http://dev.appaware.com/ which has an API that you could use to find applications registered via their service.

However what I would like to be able to do is retrieve the apps within a category and list their details on a website.

Any pointers etc. greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use https://42matters.com/api/advanced-query-api in order to retrieve the apps within a category and quite some more. Here is a showcase - https://42matters.com/app-market-explorer/android

Answer (score 1):

No, at the moment there isn't.